# Angular 5 HTTP Interceptor not setting withCredentials

Tags: angular5

I need to intercept all of my http calls and set `{withCredentials : true }`.
So I built the following interceptor.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpsRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const changedReq = req.clone({withCredentials:true});
    return next.handle(changedReq);
  }
}
```

I placed a debugger to make sure it is running.  and it runs fine in all requests.
The problem that the `{withCredentials:true}` is being ignored, unless I put it within every post and post. (which is why I have created this).

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever work this out?
I've just tested your code out and it works fine for me.

Do you have a repro?